# How to create a multiple-choice test in R Markdown [HTML]

Tags: r, r-markdown, multiple-choice

I'm trying to prepare a quiz/test for my students. It's a HTML book (the quiz is just a part of the book). So, basically, this test will have questions with one correct answer.
For example:

```
What is the capital city of Germany?
A) Copenhagen
B) Riga
C) Berlin
D) Bucharest
```

If the student selects option A, the following answer will appear: `Nope, Copenhagen is the capital of Denmark.`

If the student selects option B, the following answer will appear: `Nope, Riga is the capital of Latvia.`

If the student selects option C, the following answer will appear: `Correct.`

If the student selects option D, the following answer will appear: `Nope, Bucharest is the capital of Romania.`

I need to knit the codes to HTML. I don't want to use a package.

Comment: Use the `learnr` package.